# MD5 hash differs between machines

Tags: .net, vb.net, md5

I have a strange situation occurring. I am using the following code to create an MD5 hash for a small file. By comparing the hash from the server side with that at the client side I can test whether it has changed so that I can download any updated copy.

```vb
Public Function MD5Hash(mFileInfo As FileInfo) As String

    Dim returnString As String = ""
    Try
        Dim f As FileStream = New FileStream(mFileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 8192)
        Dim md5 As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
        md5.ComputeHash(f)
        returnString = GenerateHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(md5.Hash))
        f.Close()
    Catch
        'File doesn't exist
    End Try

    Return returnString

End Function


Public Shared Function GenerateHash(ByVal SourceText As String) As String

    'Create an encoding object to ensure the encoding standard for the source text
    Dim Ue As New UnicodeEncoding()
    'Retrieve a byte array based on the source text
    Dim ByteSourceText() As Byte = Ue.GetBytes(SourceText)
    'Instantiate an MD5 Provider object
    Dim Md5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    'Compute the hash value from the source
    Dim ByteHash() As Byte = Md5.ComputeHash(ByteSourceText)
    'And convert it to String format for return

    Return Convert.ToBase64String(ByteHash)

End Function
```

The problem is that at the server side I get one hash and at the client end I get a different hash even though the files are identical. The client is always on WinXP 32bit with .NET2.0, the server is Win2008 64bit with .NET4.0

I have tried zipping the file on the server and extracting it on the client to ensure the file isn't getting modified in the download process but still I get the same hash mismatch.

Comment: `GenerateHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(md5.Hash))` This is wrong.  Hashes are not UTF8 byte sequences.

Comment: Would this be the source of my problem. What should it be instead?

Comment: Probably not.  You probably want to simply convert the bytes of the hash to base 64.

Comment: Slaks..i modified System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString to Convert.ToBase64String and now it's consistent. I can't mark your reply as answered unless you want to post your solution as the answer.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
GenerateHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(md5.Hash))
```

This code tries to parse the hash as a UTF8-encoded string.
Since the vast majority of hashes are not valid UTF8, this won't work.

Instead, you can encode the bytes into a string format, such as base 64.